# Scope and inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, scope, static

I would like to know why the compiler doesn't allow the second use of "print_all" function.

I have to give an example of a bad thing that could happen if the compiler would allow it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using std::list;
class foo {
    class bar : public foo {
        static void print_all(list<foo *> &L) {
            list<foo *> LF;
            list<bar *> LB;
                print_all(LF); // works fine
                print_all(LB); // static semantic error

        }
    };
};
```

Comment: A `list<T>` is not a `list<U>` if `T` and `U` are different types.

Comment: But class bar inherits from class foo

Comment: That doesn't matter.  `T` and `U` are different types.  If you need to be convinced, try to assign a `list<foo*>` to a `list<bar*>` and vice-versa.  If simple assignment doesn't work, you shouldn't expect a function call to work.

Comment: *But class bar inherits from class foo* -- Maybe you have used Java, where a `foo` and a `bar` seem to be interchangeable if `foo` and `bar` have the same base class.  But this is not Java, it's C++.

Answer (score 1):

`list<foo *>` is an unrelated type to `list<bar *>`. The function is specified to accept one, but not the other.

> But class bar inherits from class foo

That is irrelevant, because the argument of your function isn't `foo&`. What's relevant is whether `list<bar *>` inherits `list<foo *>`. It doesn't. `std::list` does not have a base class.